# Random choosing number in array without repeated

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have a algorithm to randomly select element `t` in a array with out repeated. This is more detail of algorithm
[image]

It can explain as folowing:

1. Initial a array index u that stores the index of numbers from 1 to k (line 1 to 3)
2. Set initial of gamma from k and reduce by one for each iteration. The purpose of gamma is for without repeated (line 4,9,10)
3. Random choose a number t from 1 to N(at the j=1, choose 1 to k, N are nonrepated number), and then put the number to the end of array.
4. Repate the step 2 to 3
5. If gamma =0,reset gamma=k
   This function will return the t.

For example, I have a array `A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], k=9 =size(A), N=12` (From 1 to 9, number select only one time). Now I want to use this algorithm to randomly select number t from array A. This is my code. However, it does not similar the line 6 in the algorithm. Is it right? Let see my code help me

```
function nonRepeat
    k=9;
    u=1:k; % initial value of index
    N=12
    gamma=k;
    for j=1:N
        index=randi(gamma,1); % use other choosing
        t=u(index)
        %%swapping
        temp=u(t);
        u(t)=u(gamma);
        u(gamma)=temp;
        gamma=gamma-1;
        if gamma==0 
          gamma=k;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think you can begin by formatting the code more neatly. Then, explain what you mean by it does not work well.

Comment: I clean it. I run it but one element is choose 2 times in the range 1 to k

Comment: @user8264, how do you know it selects one number twice? I just gives one number.

Answer (score 0):

I think `index=randi(gamma,1);` is not right because it says select number `t` randomly but you select `index` randomly and assign `t=u(index)`.

See if it works,

```
k = 9;
u = 1 : k;
N = 12;
gamma = k;
for j = 1 : N
    t = randi(gamma,1);
    temp = u(t);
    u(t) = u(gamma);
    u(gamma) = temp;
    gamma = gamma - 1;
    if gamma == 0 
      gamma = k;
    end
end
```

Comment: @ Kamtal. It is wrong, your output is 6 2 7 3 4 3 2 2 1 3 9 8. Let see the numbers that have index from 1 to 9: 2 appears twice time. It is wrong. In the range from 1 to k, each number must appear 1 time

Comment: @user8264, how do you get `6 2 7 3 4 3 2 2 1 3 9 8` using `nonrepeat`?

Comment: I just run your code. It is your result. My expected result is that each number only appears one time in range 1 to k

Comment: @user8264, you have `9` numbers and you want a sequence length of `12` so how can each number appear just once?? maybe change `N` to `9` or change `k` to `12`.

Comment: for range from 1 to 9, it will appears one times, and range from 10 to 12 it also appear one time. The all range from 1 to 12 will has some element appears twice time. Let see the original algorithm in my question

Comment: @user8264, Isn't `u` the answer? it gives `6,8,1,4,2,3,9,5,7` each number once.